# Pattern to work around the static value of a python default argument

Tags: python

Python has this *stunning* characteristic that default parameters are evaluated once - at the time the function/method is defined:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
def some_func(ts: datetime = datetime.now()):
    print("What time is it 'now'?",ts)

some_func()
time.sleep(5)   # sleeps 5 seconds
some_func()
```

Prints:

```
What time is it 'now'? 2023-08-08 18:43:43.697853
What time is it 'now'? 2023-08-08 18:43:43.697853
```

Yes this behavior is documented. It is also beyond my prior experience having worked in dozens of languages since the early eighties.  More recent languages such as scala (and java before that) certainly do not take that angle on it.   Is there any pattern to use that can achieve the same result as evaluating default values *at invocation time* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the default to None.

Then add a guard clause to set the value to your dynamic default value if the parameter is None.

This is especially important when you want the default parameter to be an empty list, dict, or other collection.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
def some_func(ts: datetime = None):
    if ts is None:
        ts=datetime.now()
    print("What time is it 'now'?",ts)

some_func()
time.sleep(5)   # sleeps 5 seconds
some_func()
```

Output

```
What time is it 'now'? 2023-08-08 21:07:07.692347
What time is it 'now'? 2023-08-08 21:07:12.697683
```

Comment: you and tom provided the same answer within seconds of each other.  Who gets awarded?

Comment: flip a coin?  technically I'm sure this could probably be marked a duplicate of an existing question.

Answer (score 3):

This problem also arises with mutable default arguments. The solution is the same: Use a sentinel value for the default argument (e.g. `None`), then check for it in the function body:

```
def some_func(ts: datetime=None):
    if ts is None:
        ts = datetime.now()
    print("What time is it 'now'?",ts)
```

Comment: you and nigh_anxiety provided the same answer within seconds of each other.  Who gets awarded?

Comment: gave it to him since he needs it more ;)

Comment: @WestCoastProjects You should always accept the best, most helpful answer.  For equally good answers, it usually makes sense to accept the answer that was posted first.  I would say that you should generally ignore reputation when deciding which answer to accept.

Comment: They were equal answers that came in within seconds of each other. I chose a random tie breaker

Comment: @WestCoastProjects No problem, that answer is perfectly good.